# Passing views to a second fragment screen does not display them correctly

Tags: android, android-fragments, binding

I am getting an an error when I try to display 2 input views.
They are captured in one fragment screen and then I try to display them on a second fragment screen.
The navigation works but they display as resources?... i do not even know what it is called.

This is the setOnClickListener that calls up that screen. I suspect it has something to go with safeArgs

```
binding.buttonConfirm.setOnClickListener{
    val username = binding.editTextUsername.toString()
    val password = binding.editTextPassword.toString()
    val action = LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToWelcomeFragment(username, password) // this is generated class due to nav graph
    findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

[image]

in Debugger i added some watches
[image]

I am a newbie to Android, and to stackoverflow as a poster.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `toString()` on the `EditText` and not actually getting the text the user has entered - to do that, you need to call `getText()` which in Kotlin code, you can do via the `text` property:

```
val username = binding.editTextUsername.text.toString()
val password = binding.editTextPassword.text.toString()
val action = LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToWelcomeFragment(username, password) // this is generated class due to nav graph
findNavController().navigate(action)
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, lol.. I was almost afraid to ask... was fearing a bad experience on stackoverflow.

Comment: Code that shows what you were doing, a screenshot, and logs? I think you did a great job with your question! Best of luck going forward :)

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the view itself instead of its value. To do so, grab the value, not the view.

```
binding.buttonConfirm.setOnClickListener{
val username = binding.editTextUsername.text.toString()
val password = binding.editTextPassword.text.toString()
val action = LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToWelcomeFragment(username, password) // this is generated class due to nav graph
    findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

**Alternatively, you can pass data between destinations with Bundle objects.**

Create a Bundle object and pass it to the destination using navigate(), as shown below:

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString("username", binding.editTextUserName.text.toString())
bundle.putString("password", binding.editTextPassword.text.toString())
view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.actionLoginFragmentToWelcomeFragment, bundle)
```

In your receiving destination’s code, use the getArguments() method to retrieve the Bundle and use its contents:

```
binding.textViewUserName.text = arguments?.getString("username")
binding.textViewPassword.text =arguments?.getString("password")
```